# I'm getting error during sniff packet using scapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, scapy

My code is here:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
print(os.sys.path)
from scapy.all import*
def sniff(interface):
    scapy.sniff(iface=interface, store=False, prn=process_sniffed_packet)

def process_sniffed_packet(packet):
    print(packet)

sniff("eth0")
```

And got the error code like this:

python3 row.py

```py
['/home/kali/Desktop', '/usr/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.7', '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.7/dist-packages']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "row.py", line 11, in <module>
    sniff("eth0")
  File "row.py", line 6, in sniff
    scapy.sniff(iface=interface, store=False, prn=process_sniffed_packet)
AttributeError: module 'scapy' has no attribute 'sniff'
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: `sniff` instead of `scapy.sniff`.... check your imports

Answer (score 0):

You just imported all available functions from scapy with `from scapy.all import *`
which means you have to use `sniff` instead of `scapy.sniff`

If you want to use `scapy.sniff` you have to change your import to `import scapy.all as scapy`

Note: There is a `sniff` function in `scapy.all` but you are defining a new `sniff` function (line 5). Rename it so that you don't get name conflicts.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
print(os.sys.path)
from scapy.all import *
def mysniff(interface):
    sniff(iface=interface, store=False, prn=process_sniffed_packet)

def process_sniffed_packet(packet):
    print(packet)

mysniff("eth0")
```

Comment: after put the sniff i got the error                                                                                                                                 sniff() got an unexpected keyword argument 'iface'

Comment: thats because you defined a function named ```sniff``` in line 5 ```def sniff(interface):```.  Change the name of your function to something else. naming your function ```sniff``` is causing a conflict with the ```sniff``` function of scapy.